# How do I pass an md5 hash of email addresses in URL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Using:

- MySQL 5.1.68-cll
- PHPmyadmin 3.5.5
- Interspire Email Marketer 6.1.2

In Interspire, in my email newsletters' links, I want to pass a variable e=[MD5 hash of that subscriber's email]. Any thoughts on how I could do that? Do I need to create a custom field called e and run a function that will populate it with the hashed values, or is there a way to do it on the fly?

Also, is there a way to create the hash everytime someone joins my email list?

Thank you!

Comment: as this is very specific to how Interspire works their own support forum would be a better place to ask. http://www.interspire.com/support/

Comment: Their forum is dead, and their support requires paying for a maintenance license. Mine expired. I'm sure stack ninjas can provide ideas that are just as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my database, I want to create a column that will contain the hashes. Let's call it hash_of_email. Is it possible to define it so that it always creates a hash of the email address everytime a new record is created, and create a hash for all existing ones? If so how can I do it? Ideally I'd do all this in PHP but I'm using Interspire so I don't want to edit any of their files because I don't know PHP well enough, or their code well enough. What I can do is manipulate the db and call on custom variables in the HTML editor

If you INNODB as your storage engine for the table, you can do that.

Assume that you add a new column `hash_of_email` to keep hash value for `email` column.

**To update current value**

```
UPDATE `table` SET `hash_of_value` = MD5(`email`)
```

**To update new record automatically**

Please refer to [MySQL's trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en///create-trigger.html), the one you need is a BEFORE CREATE TRIGGER on `table`. Let's do it:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `TG_table__before_insert`
    ON `table` BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`hash_of_email` = MD5(NEW.`email`);
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Good luck,

Answer (score 0):

In modern version of mysql you can just

```
select md5(email_address) from whatevertable;
```

of you can also do it to an already retrieve email by

```
$md5edEmail = md5($email_address);
```

Comment: In my database, I want to create a column that will contain the hashes. Let's call it hash_of_email. Is it possible to define it so that it always creates a hash of the email address everytime a new record is created, and create a hash for all existing ones? If so how can I do it?

Ideally I'd do all this in PHP but I'm using Interspire so I don't want to edit any of their files because I don't know PHP well enough, or their code well enough. What I can do is manipulate the db and call on custom variables in the HTML editor.

Comment: Its possible but the exact implementation is going to be app and db specific. A lot of MVC systems have the concept of a before insert/update event that could be leverage to hash and update/set you new field. Alternatively a db trigger may be created to do it transparently. Hopefully this will let you know what trees to bark to get a solution

Answer (score 0):

In both PHP and MySQL, md5 is a standard function. You can use it like this:

PHP:

```
$e = md5($Email);
```

MySQL:

```
md5(EmailField)
```

Both can be used in queries as well. And since you plan on passing it as a query string in the URL, it's safe to encode it like this PHP example:

```
$EncodedEmail = urlencode($e);//where $e is from above.
```

And of course you'll have to use `urldecode()` to reverse it.

More info:
You'll simply use the md5 function like I've shown within a MySQL query. But I am not familiar with Interspire so I cannot give you any advice on it.

As for using the md5 function in a query, here's an example:

```
$strSQL = "Update MyTable Set
  EmailHash = md5(EmailAddress)";
```

But I'm a little lost when you say that you cannot use PHP. You'll need to be able to move PHP variables to the mail and mail info to the PHP code at some point.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to pass the variable in the HTML editor of the newsletter in Interspire, so I cannot use PHP. I can pass it as a custom field, like e=%%hash_of_email%%, where hash_of_email is the name of the custom field. How can I populate the custom field in MySQL with the hash so when it's called on it provides the value?

Comment: md5 is not the option if you want 2 way encryption. md5 is a hashing algorithm, once md5'd there is no going back. what you need to look into is the php crypto stuff for encryption vs hashing

Comment: side not the output of md5 is url safe no need to do any urlencodeing (but there is nothing wrong with url encoding everything that goes up there just as a matter of practice)

Comment: The md5 hash is just gonna be used as an identifier for analytics. There will not be any need to decipher it.

Comment: So using md5(EmailField) in MySQL would accomplish what I'm looking for? Could you provide some basic instructions on where to put that code? Thanks!